# Не запускается Genymotion Google Nexus

Tags: android, genymotion, эмулятор

У меня запускаются все девайсы Genymotion, кроме Google Nexus, Custom Phone и Galaxy. А мне нужен виртуал девайс с API >= 21

Ошибку выдаёт такую:

> Unable to start virtual device
>   The virtual device got no IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genymotion работает на основе VirtualBox. В большинстве случаев причина подобных проблем кроется в настройке сети соответствующей виртуальной машины VirtualBox.

Открывайте настройки виртуальной машины и проверяйте настройки сети для неё.

Иногда проблема может быть связана ещё с BIOS хоста (поддержка виртуализации).

Кстати, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436253/genymotion-the-virtual-device-got-no-ip-address) что-то подобное уже обсуждалось.

Comment: 1) Мой процессор не поддерживает виртуализацию. 2) Уже выполнял указанные по ссылке шаги, безрезультатно.

Comment: В таком случае биться с эмуляторами скорее всего бессмысленно и единственный способ организовать отладку - искать нужное устройство в магазине или у знакомых. Если программа пишется в интересах работодателя или заказчика, можно попытаться договориться о том, чтобы Вам предоставили нужное "железо". Кто знает, может Вам пойдут на встречу.